# "No input file specified" when using PHP with symlink

Tags: php, apache, symlink

I have setup a website with ISPConfig.

In that website root I made symlink `test/ -> /var/test/`

`/var/test/` contains two files - test.php and test.html. test.html works fine, but when I try to run test.php I get a white page with text `No input file specified.`

My website is auto-configured by ISPConfig running Apache 2.2.22. Here is an excerpt from config - please ask if you need to see more:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php` in top of .htaccess